Permutations of groups with exclusive members
Suppose we have a set $A = \{ a_1, a_2, ... , a_m \}$ and we want to make sets of $3$ elements. We will have $m \choose 3$ different sets. Let's call this new combinations set as $B=\{\{a_1, a_2, a_3\}, \{a_1, a_2, a_4\} , ... , \{a_{m-2},a_{m-1}, a_m\}\}$. The elements of this set will be referred as $b_i$. Now what I want is to know the number of permutations of $k$ elements of $B$ such that for all the pair of sets $b^p_i, b^p_j$ belonging to the permutation $p$, all the pair of elements of the sets $a^{b^p_i}_k, a^{b^p_j}_l$ are distinct to each other.
For example, for $k=2$, the permutation $\left(\{a_1, a_2, a_3\}, \{a_1, a_2, a_4\}\right)$ would be invalid, because $a_1$ and $a_2$ are in both sets of the permutation. However, the permutation $\left(\{a_1, a_2, a_3\}, \{a_4, a_5, a_6\}\right)$ is valid since none of the inner elements repeats within the other set.

In your question you ask for the number of permutations, and in your example you describe combinations. Can you clarify?

@UriGeorgePeterzil I meant permutation, I have already edited the question.

So, you have $m\choose3$ $3$-sets. Given any one of them, there are ${m-3\choose3}$ that are disjoint from it. So, for $k=2$, the answer is ${m\choose3}{m-3\choose3}$.

Reasoning the same way (if I interpret the question the way you intend), for $k=3$ it would be ${m\choose3}{m-3\choose3}{m-6\choose3}$, and so on for any value of $k$.

But perhaps I misunderstand. Is $({a,b,c),(a,d,e)}$ OK (where $a,b,c,d,e$ are all different)?

@GerryMyerson No, that would not be permitted, all pair of elements within and between the sets have to be distinct. In fact, the inner sets are a combination of elements, so they will always be distinct between each other, but the challenging part is for the permutation. But I don't see why what you said is wrong

Then I think my earlier comments settle the matter, don't they?

@GerryMyerson Yes, I think so. So, just for clarification: the permutations between two elements of two sets it's just the multiplication of the amount of elements of each other?
